# Substitution encoding in python

Tags: python

I made a substitution cipher which generates random dictionary with which the plain text characters are replaced.

Here is the code:

```
import random

alphabets=' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789~!@#$%^&*()_+|:"<>-=[];,.?'
class HCPyEncoder:    
    def encode(self,plaintext):       
        length=len(alphabets)
        arr=range(0,length)
        random.shuffle(arr)
        pad,cipher="",""
        dictionary={}        
        for i in range(0,length):
            pad=pad+alphabets[arr[i]]
            dictionary[alphabets[i]]=alphabets[arr[i]]
        for i in plaintext:
            if i in dictionary:
                i=dictionary[i]
            cipher=cipher+i
        return cipher,pad

    def decode(self,ciphertext,pad):
        dictionary={}
        plaintext=""
        for i in range(len(pad)):
            dictionary[pad[i]]=alphabets[i]

        for i in ciphertext:
            if i in dictionary:
                i=dictionary[i]
            plaintext=plaintext+i
        return plaintext

encoder=HCPyEncoder()
ciphertext,pad=encoder.encode("Psycho Coder")
plaintext=encoder.decode(ciphertext,pad)
print "Ciphertext : ",ciphertext
print "Plaintext : ",plaintext
```

But the problem is that every time it generates a new key or pad, so if the secret message is sent to someone it cannot be recovered.

So I want to give it a fixed substitution dictionary, and not a random one, which will be used for generating every cipher text.

I am a beginner at python so please help me with the code.

Comment: use a seed to initialize the "random" , that seed will be the key you and your friend need to have in common to communicate.

Comment: The reason Marcin asked that you put the code in your question is that stackoverflow questions should be self-contained.  They are not useful to new users in the future is the link to your code breaks.  The answer I think is going to be easy but hopefully no one will give you an answer until you add the code.

Comment: For cryptographic purposes i use the more random python function `os.urandom(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you would simply eliminate the following line:

```
random.shuffle(arr)
```

As this is what generates a new pad at each run of the code.  Replace that line with an array of a given value for each index, 0-25; I suppose you can choose, i.e. arr= [5,2,20...]

Comment: can you please explain it with some code. I am an absolute beginner in python. My main languages are Java and .NET aqnd I am good in them But at present I have to learn python.